# apache wicket - column link inside DataTable on table change (lets say filter and getting 0 rows) the opened link page fail

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

scenario : I am using data table with columns
one of the columns is link .
on run time I calculate the link created
the problem start when:
1. opennig table page P1 
2. I clicked on link open in new tab 
2.new tab is created with this URL

```
 mit:8080/backoffice/?4-1.ILinkListener-MainPanelComponentWrapper-MainPanelComponent-table-gridForm-grid-body-rows-3-cells-2-cell-link
```

which is a component on P1 ,this tab generate P2.

3. changing P1 ,filtering on ajax and the table is empty so table-gridForm has no data
4. refreshing P2
5. getting exception 
   org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Component 'MainPanelComponentWrapper:MainPanelComponent:table:gridForm:grid:body:rows:1:cells:2:cell:link' has been removed from page.

i need to create a redirected link that the new page woul be linked to .
how can i achive it ?

```
 public class LinkPropertyColumn<T extends IEntity> extends BOPropertyColumn<T, String> implements IBOExportableColumn<T, String, Object> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String headerTilte;
private GridViewType navigateTo;
private String routingByProperty;
private String entityId;
private String navigateToDynamicFunction;
private Map<String, String> filterByMap;
protected BOLinkPanel<T> linkPanel ;


    public LinkPropertyColumn(String displayModel, String propertyToSortBy, String propertyExpression, String entityId,
        String routingByProperty, String headerTilte, String navigateToDynamic) {
    super(Model.of(displayModel), propertyToSortBy, propertyExpression);
    this.headerTilte = headerTilte;
    this.entityId = entityId;
    this.navigateToDynamicFunction = navigateToDynamic;
    this.routingByProperty = routingByProperty;

}

@Override
public Component getHeader(String componentId) {
    return new Label(componentId, headerTilte);
}

@Override
public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<T>> item, String componentId, final IModel<T> rowModel) {
     linkPanel = new BOLinkPanel<T>(componentId, rowModel, getPropertyExpression()) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        void onLinkClicked() {
            LinkPropertyColumn.this.onLinkClicked(rowModel);
        }
    };
    item.add(linkPanel);

}

public void onLinkClicked(IModel<T> rowModel) {

    doing stuff...
    params.add(HomePage.ENTITY_ID, idProperty);
    final Object routingProperty = routingByProperty == null ? idProperty : BeanUtils.getProperty(object, routingByProperty);
    params.set(HomePage.ROUTING_PROPERTY, routingProperty);
    HomePage homePage = new HomePage(params);
    final RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
    requestCycle.setResponsePage(homePage);

}
```

}

}

and :

```
 public abstract class BOLinkPanel<T> extends Panel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @param id
 */
public BOLinkPanel(String id, IModel<T> model, String propertyExpression) {
    super(id);
    AbstractLink link = getLink();

    link.add(new Label("caption", new PropertyModel<String>(model.getObject(), propertyExpression)));
    add(link);
}

protected AbstractLink getLink() {
    Link<Void> link = new AjaxFallbackLink<Void>("link") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            BOLinkPanel.this.onLinkClicked();
        }

//          @Override
//          public void onClick() {
//              BOLinkPanel.this.onLinkClicked();
//
//          }
    };
    return link;
}

    abstract void onLinkClicked();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

i did :

```
 requestCycle.setResponsePage(HomePage.class, params);
```